# fmt:formatNumber throws exception if number has length >= 20 digit?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a currency field which has length > 20 digit

E.g : 99999999999999999999

and when i used:

```
<fmt:formatNumber
     value="${crudShipmentForm.invoiceVat}"
     pattern="###,###,###,###,##0.000"  />
```

I received `NumberFormatException` ?
How can I format this field to currency using `fmt:formatNumber` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your number is too large.

Here's the relevant code from [`FormatNumberSupport`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/FormatNumberSupport.java#FormatNumberSupport):

```
if (input instanceof String) {
    try {
    if (((String) input).indexOf('.') != -1) {
                // String value is interpreted as a double
        input = Double.valueOf((String) input);
    } else {
                // String value is interpreted as a long
        input = Long.valueOf((String) input);
    }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    throw new JspException(
                Resources.getMessage("FORMAT_NUMBER_PARSE_ERROR", input),
        nfe);
    }
}
```

Your number is way beyond the scope of `long`

Answer (score 2):

You've exceeded the maximum value of `long` which is `9223372036854775807`.

This indicates that you're using `String` to hold the number instead of `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`. It's not only technically the wrong type, but EL will also coerce it to `long`. Fix it accordingly.

```
private BigDecimal invoiceVat; // And fix getter/setter as well.
```

or if you really cannot change the type for some odd reason, do it in the getter

```
public BigDecimal getInvoiceVat() {
    return new BigDecimal(invoiceVat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `NumberFormat` for numbers bigger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`. You should use [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) instead of `NumberFormat` class.

Comment: We're talking about JSP, not Java, and I don't know of a JSP DecimalFormat tag, at least not in JSTL

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to format the integer digits in thousands, in which case using the `pattern="###,##0.000"` should do the trick.